# What mistake I am committing while retreiving the req.body parser data in nodejs from handlebar page?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, multer, body-parser

I am trying to get the pop-up form data into nodejs api route via body-parser but its showing undefined. I have installed and included all the necessary body-parser packages in app.js and this respective route code file also.

Here is the handlebar form code:

```
<form name="contactform" id="contactform" class="contact-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/updateProfile" method="post">
      <div class="cd-popup-container" style="">
        <p style="">
          <a href="" class="cd-popup-close cd-close-button">
            <i class="fa fa-times" style="pointer-events:none;"></i>
          </a>
        </p>

        <div class="name">
          <label for="name">Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="email">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="locationEdit">
          <label for="locationEdit">Location</label>
          <input type="text" id="locationEdit" name="locationEdit" />
        </div>
        <div class="oldPass">
          <label for="oldPass">Old Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="oldPass" name="oldPass" />
        </div>
         <div class="newPass">
          <label for="newPass">New Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="newPass" name="newPass" />
        </div>
        <div class="confirmPass">
          <label for="confirmPass">Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="confirmPass" name="confirmPass" />
        </div>
        <div class="uploadAvatar">
         <label for="uploadAvatar">Upload Avatar --- >>></label>
         <input type="text" id="uploadAvatar" name="uploadAvatar" disabled/>
       </div>
        <div class="avatarFileUpload">
          <input type="file" name="avatarFileUpload" accept="image/*" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Update</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the `POST` route code:
I am getting the req.body.name and all other body attributes as undefined.

```
router.post('/api/updateProfile', function(req,res,next){
console.log("yes it came under profile api");

req.checkBody('name', 'Empty Name').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid Email').isEmail();
req.checkBody('location', 'Empty Location').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('oldPass', 'Empty Password').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('newPass', 'Password do not match').equals(req.body.confirmPass);

console.log("avatar = "+ req.user.avatar);
console.log("body name = "+ req.body.name);

fs.unlink(req.user.avatar, function(err,success){
       if(err)
       {
         console.log("unlink error = "+error);
          // return console.log(err);
       }
       else {
           console.log('old avatar deleted successfully');
           upload3(req,res,function(err) {
               if(err) {
                 console.log("Error = "+ err);
                   return;
               }
               else
               {
                 console.log('new avatar uploaded successfully req.files[0].path = '+ req.files[0].path);
                 User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user.id},{$set: {"avatar" :req.files[0].path}},
                 function (error, data) {
                       if (error) {
                           console.log(error);
                       }
                       else {
                         console.log('new avatar path updated successfully');
                       }
                     })
               }
             })
       }
  });

  User.updateMany({_id:req.user.id},
    {$set:
      {
        "name" :req.body.name,
        "location":req.body.location
      }
    },
    function (error, success) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("error");
      }  else if(req.body.newPass != '' && req.body.confirmPass != ''){
        var user = new User();
      user.setPassword(req.body.newPass);
      console.log("Password reset successfully");
    }
});

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're missing wiring multer into the route. I couldn't see your setup code for the app, but you should most likely have your POST route be defined with multer like this:

```
router.post("/api/updateProfile", upload.single("avatarFileUpload"), (req, res, next) => {
  // req.file is the `avatarFileUpload` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
});
```

The reason why you don't see anything in `req.body` is that the incoming request is `'Content-type: multipart/form-data'` and body-parser package is meant to parse incoming JSON request. Such request has `'Content-type: application/json'`.